# Can someone explain the following sentence in simpler language?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain the following sentence to me in simpler language.

I'm not a native English speaker. I was faced a problem while reading a particular sentence from O Henry's "One Thousand Dollars".

> You could rent Madison Square Garden for one evening with it, and lecture your audience, if you should have one, on the precariousness of the profession of heir presumptive.

I know **precarious** means uncertain and **presumptive** is of the nature of a presumption; presumed in the absence of further information.

Comment: An *heir presumptive* is an heir who may be superseded (eg a princess who is overtaken by a younger brother). See [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heir-presumptive?q=heir+presumptive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun phrase in question is certainly convoluted. O. Henry liked using fancy language.

- *the precariousness **of** the profession **of** heir presumptive*

Note that it's actually three noun phrases; the second one is the object of the first preposition *of*.

- *the profession of heir presumptive*

And the third one is the object of the second preposition *of*.

- *heir presumptive*

Starting from the bottom, *heir presumptive* is a fixed phrase. It means 'the person who is presumed to be the heir', which can mean the next Duke, the future owner of the company, or the person who will succeed some other person in an important role. The *presumption* comes about because nothing about inheritance is certain until someone dies, and even then it's often complicated, so one can only presume.

Moving up to the second noun phrase, we note that *heir presumptive* is not a profession, so this is figurative language. It refers to the waiting that an heir presumptive must endure before inheriting. Whatever that entails.

Finally, *precariousness* is predicated. You're right about the meaning of *precarious*, but *precariousness* is an abstract noun meaning 'the state of being precarious'.

So tell the audience  that being an heir apparent is a very precarious situation to find oneself in.

Comment: Where the order cannot be disturbed by a future event, such as the birth of a child somewhere, the heir is said to be an *heir apparent*. Prince Charles is an *heir apparent*. (He would not have been given the title *Prince of Wales* had he not been). However his mother, when Princess Elizabeth, was an *heir presumptive*, for had George VI sired a son, that child would have taken precedence. The law has now been changed so that females rank equal to males in the order of succession, something Julia Gillard, then PM of Australia described, perhaps in jest, as *giving every Sheila a chance*.

Comment: I would add that the "profession of heir presumptive" implies that one is relying for their livelihood on the presumption that they will be an heir. Treating one's future inheritance as a presumed source of livelihood is most precarious.